# Why is my iFFT image coming out with a mirrored copy?

Tags: c++, image, fft

So i'm using KissFFT (kiss_fftnd) for converting an image to frequency domain and back again. Things seem to be working reasonably well however we're getting odd results.

input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LttmD.jpg

result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/geIKi.jpg

I honestly have no idea what's going on, any help would be much appreciated.

Below is our fast pass, converting from spatial domain to frequency domain.

```
int M = input->width;
int N = input->height;
int width = input->width;
int height = input->height;

int mDim[2] = { N, M };
const int numDim = 2; //number of dimensions

kiss_fft_cpx *cinRed = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];
kiss_fft_cpx *cinGreen = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];
kiss_fft_cpx *cinBlue = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];

kiss_fft_cpx *coutRed = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];
kiss_fft_cpx *coutGreen = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];
kiss_fft_cpx *coutBlue = new kiss_fft_cpx[width * height];

kiss_fftnd_cfg state = kiss_fftnd_alloc (mDim, numDim, 0, 0, 0);

int k=0;
for (int i=0;i<M;++i)
{
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        PF_Pixel32 curPixel = *sampleIntegral128(*input, i, j);

        cinRed[k].r     = curPixel.red;
        cinGreen[k].r   = curPixel.green;
        cinBlue[k].r    = curPixel.blue;

        k++;
    }
}

kiss_fftnd(state,cinRed,coutRed);//coutRed contains 2D fft results for img1 (red channel)
kiss_fftnd(state,cinGreen,coutGreen);
kiss_fftnd(state,cinBlue,coutBlue);

for(unsigned int l=0; l<width; l++)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        int index = l * height + i;

        PF_Pixel32 *outPix = sampleIntegral128(*output, l, i);

        outPix->alpha    = 1.0;
        outPix->red      = coutRed[index].r;
        outPix->green    = coutGreen[index].r;
        outPix->blue     = coutBlue[index].r;

    }
}

delete[] cinRed;
delete[] cinGreen;
delete[] cinBlue;
delete[] coutRed;
delete[] coutGreen;
delete[] coutBlue;
```

Below is our second pass, converting from frequency to spatial domain.

```
int mDim[2] = { N, M };
const int numDim = 2; //number of dimensions

kiss_fft_cpx *cinRed =  new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];
kiss_fft_cpx *coutRed = new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];
kiss_fft_cpx *cinGreen =  new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];
kiss_fft_cpx *coutGreen = new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];
kiss_fft_cpx *cinBlue =  new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];
kiss_fft_cpx *coutBlue = new kiss_fft_cpx[N * M];

kiss_fftnd_cfg state = kiss_fftnd_alloc (mDim, numDim, 1, 0, 0);

int k=0;
for (int i=0;i<M;++i)
{
    for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        PF_Pixel32 curPixel = *sampleIntegral128(*input, i, j);

        cinRed[k].r = curPixel.red;
        cinRed[k].i = 0;
        cinGreen[k].r = curPixel.green;
        cinGreen[k].i = 0;
        cinBlue[k].r = curPixel.blue;
        cinBlue[k].i = 0;

        k++;
    }
}

kiss_fftnd(state,cinRed,coutRed);//coutRed contains 2D fft results for img1 (red channel)
kiss_fftnd(state,cinGreen,coutGreen);
kiss_fftnd(state,cinBlue,coutBlue);

for(unsigned int l=0; l<width; l++)
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<height; i++)
    {
        int index = i * height + l;

        PF_Pixel32 *outPix = sampleIntegral128(*output, l, i);

        outPix->alpha    = 1.0;
        outPix->red      = sqrt(pow(coutRed[index].r, 2.0) + pow(coutRed[index].i, 2.0));
        outPix->green    = sqrt(pow(coutGreen[index].r, 2.0) + pow(coutGreen[index].i, 2.0));
        outPix->blue     = sqrt(pow(coutBlue[index].r, 2.0) + pow(coutBlue[index].i, 2.0));

    }
}

delete[] cinRed;
delete[] cinGreen;
delete[] cinBlue;
delete[] coutRed;
delete[] coutGreen;
delete[] coutBlue;
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo, thanks for the comment, sorry about that thought I had included the code, see above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are throwing away the imaginary component of the FFT. You need to preserve both the real and imaginary components of the output of the FFT to be able to invert the operation.

Comment: Hey that worked great!
Can't believe I missed that thank you. Now to solve the multiplication and memory issues we're having. 
Thanks again for the help, owe you one.

Comment: odd I thought I checked that, on both yours and the other answers. I've checked it again let me know if it doesn't work.